# Moving and merging elements in array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm quite new to Java but I've got the basics...

So I have an array of 4 ints which I need to move to the front of the array, or merge them if they are equal so:

- {0,1,0,2} turns into {1,2,0,0}
- {2,1,0,2} turns into {2,1,2,0}
- {1,1,0,0} turns into {2,0,0,0}
- {0,2,0,2} turns into {4,0,0,0}
- {1,1,3,3} turns into {2,6,0,0}
- {2,2,2,2} turns into {4,4,0,0} etc...

Here's what I have so far:

```
public void combine(int[] row)
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length-1; i++)
    {
        if (row[i] == 0 && row[i+1] > 0) //move
        {
           row[i] = row[i+1];
           row[i+1] = 0;
        }
        if (row [i] == row[i+1] && row[i] > 0) //merge
        {
            row[i] = 2 * row[i];
            row[i+1] = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(row[0]);
    System.out.println(row[1]);
    System.out.println(row[2]);
    System.out.println(row[3]);
}
```

The problem is:

- {0,1,0,2} becomes {1,0,2,0}
- {0,2,0,2} becomes {2,0,2,0}
- {1,1,3,3} becomes {2,3,3,0}
- {2,2,2,2} becomes {4,2,2,0}

It doesn't merge fully, or it only moves and merges once for some reason? I would like to know what I am doing wrong so I can learn, thanks!

Please, could anyone help me with this? I would really appreciate it... Thanks!

Comment: I see your problem as having two steps.  First, you need to sort the array to push all zeroes to the right.  This sort of has the flavor of a bubble sort.  Next, you need to do a combine step where you optionally will combine two entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you will need to perform a move to front, then merge your elements and then move to front again. The merge is relatively simple to implement, examine even indexes in the array; if two adjacent elements are equal multiply one by two and set the other to 0. Something like,

```
private static void merge(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < arr.length; i += 2) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {
            arr[i] *= 2;
            arr[i + 1] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I would begin with `swap`, to move elements in the array like

```
private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) {
        return;
    }
    int t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}
```

Then for *move to front*, examine each element from the left; when we get a `0` begin looking from the right for a non-zero and then *swap*

```
private static void moveToFront(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            for (int j = arr.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
                if (arr[j] != 0) {
                    swap(arr, i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, `combine`; *move to front*, *merge* and then *move to front* again

```
public static void combine(int[] row) {
    moveToFront(row);
    merge(row);
    moveToFront(row);
}
```

Finally, we can test it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = { { 0, 1, 0, 2 }, // turns into {1,2,0,0}
            { 2, 1, 0, 2 }, // turns into {2,1,2,0}
            { 1, 1, 0, 0 }, // turns into {2,0,0,0}
            { 0, 2, 0, 2 }, // turns into {4,0,0,0}
            { 1, 1, 3, 3 }, // turns into {2,6,0,0}
            { 2, 2, 2, 2 } };// turns into {4,4,0,0}
    for (int[] a : arr) {
        combine(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

And I get (as requested)

```
[1, 2, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 6, 0, 0]
[4, 4, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the move and merge in your code is only 1-step moving, while the move and merge could be 2 or more steps moving. This is not a java question but a algorithm one.

This is a two-pointer question by using i and j, i is to record the position you are going to move number in and j is the position you have reached out to the furthest to get number from.

Comment: Alright thanks! How would I implement this, exactly? So I need a nested for loop with j starting from the end of the array?

Comment: Yes. A nested loop but actually still acts O(n) complexity.